# Multiple Values in Valvalue?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in jquery and I got a very few knowledge I created an input field in which jquery grab a dropdown selected values if I put only one value in **setting value field** its working fine as I want to grab all var value in a single //Setting Value  and also want only first two letters of the selected value: like if I choose dropdown value as **Morning Class** I want only **"MO"** and same for the rest variables as Section **XI Class** I am looking for only **XI** my code is given below:

**Html Code**

```
<form id="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">            
    <div class="col-md-3">                                                            
    <div class="form-group">
    <select  id="section_id" name="section_id" class="form-control" >
    <option value="XI Class">XI Class</option>                        
    <option value="XII Class">XII Class</option>
    </select>                                                            
   <div class="col-md-3">                                                            
    <div class="form-group">
    <select  id="class_id" name="class_id" class="form-control" >
    <option value="Morning Class">Morning Class</option>              
    <option value="Morning Class">Morning Class</option>
    </select></div></div>                                                
    <div class="col-md-3">                                                            
    <div class="form-group">
    <select  id="class_id" name="class_id" class="form-control" >
    <option value="Morning Class">Morning Class</option>              
    <option value="Morning Class">Morning Class</option>
    </select></div></div>                                                
   <div class="col-md-3">                                                            
    <div class="form-group">                                             
    <input  id="input" name="input" placeholder=""                
    type="text" class="form-control "  value="" /></div></div>    
                                    </div>                             

 </form>
```

**jquery Code**

```
 $("#class_id,section_id").on("change",function(){
    //Getting Value
    var selValue = $("#class_id :selected").text();
    var selValue1 = $("#section_id :selected").text();

    //Setting Value
    $("#input").val(selValue,selValue1);
});
```

Comment: Can you describe/give an example of what you would expect out?  Eg an array of string values?  Or key/value pair?  In querystring format?  `$("form").serialize()` might be all you need.

Comment: You have multiple selects with same id. Id is meant to be unique and should be used only once per element. Not really sure what you are trying to do and what is not working.

Comment: in the section  $("#input").val(selValue,selValue1); , i want to call both var value but it not working however if delete  one var $("#input").val(selValue); then its working...and i am tring to get both values in #input Id

Comment: You can't just make up how to call functions - there's no `.val(p1, p2, p3)` method only `.val(p1)` - and what would it put in #input? which is a text box.  Do you mean to *concatenate* the values?  `$("#input).val(selValue + " " + selValue1);`.   As earlier, you need to provide an *example* of what the output would be, not just reiterate what's in the question "put both values in input" - what would that look like?